# Get multiple line response by executing command in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scripting, nsis

i am executing a command in a batch file(.bat).
This command gives me a multiple line response like

```
Get String Return value = 1
[Name]
name=john
```

and i want to get john from this output in a variable but i don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('command ^| find /i "name="') do set "name=%%B"
echo %name%
```

?

Comment: thanx npocmaka but is showing ECHO is off while i was executing.

Comment: my command is for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('call %confPath% GetIniString %datFile% Name name ^| find /i "name="') do set 

"name=%%B"
echo %name%